# Evaluating $\int_{\Omega}\frac{e^{x^2}}{e^{x^2} + e^{y^2}}dxdy $

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Title says it all.

I want to calculate $\int_{\Omega}\frac{e^{x^2}}{e^{x^2} + e^{y^2}}dxdy$ where $\Omega = [-1, 1]^2$.

It seems to defy all integration techniques. The function $e^{x^2}$ does not have a standard anti-derivative, so how do we calculate this integral?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hint. Note that, by symmetry,
$$\int_{[-1, 1]^2}\frac{e^{x^2}}{e^{x^2} + e^{y^2}}dxdy =\int_{[-1, 1]^2}\frac{e^{y^2}}{e^{x^2} + e^{y^2}}dxdy.$$
On the other hand the following integral is quite easy,
$$\int_{[-1, 1]^2}\frac{e^{x^2}}{e^{x^2} + e^{y^2}}dxdy +\int_{[-1, 1]^2}\frac{e^{y^2}}{e^{x^2} + e^{y^2}}dxdy.$$

Comment: That was so beautiful and elegant. Thank you. Managed to solve it now.

Comment: @Oria Gruber Well done!